# how to add googleAds to my site?

Tags: asp.net, adsense

I have opened an account,

but saw only option of buying ad words.

I want to add ads to my site,
all the tutorials I have found are old and related to old goolge UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding ads is not difficult. Best and most up to date help/tutorial comes from Google itself: http://support.google.com/adsense/?hl=en

Also look [here](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=pl&topic=1045719&answer=1045721&parent=1045789&rd=2)

Answer (score 0):

First create an adsense account it takes time like 2 weeks, then customize ur ads in the adsense account it automatically generates code copy the code and paste it in ur web site